# Flair up vs Flare up?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

From the CNN article [5 things to know for March 27: Tornado outbreak, Israel, SVB, Chemical spill, Ukraine](https://edition.cnn.com/2023/03/27/us/five-things-march-27-trnd/index.html):

> This evening, storms are forecast to ****flair up**** across southeastern Texas and into Louisiana, with the potential for large hail and powerful wind gusts.

Q. This sentence appears in a CNN article, but upon consulting the dictionary, it seems that "flare up" is the correct form, and "flair up" is not an accepted usage. Can you confirm if this (flare up) is accurate?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about an obvious typo. If I enter **storms are forecast to flair up** as my search string to Google, it asks me "Did you mean: *storms are forecast to **flare** up*?"

Comment: Flair isn't a verb. It's a noun.  "Flair" is homophone of "flare" (they are pronounced the same). So, this is just a typo, an error.

Answer (score 10):

Both words are homophones (/flɛr/), so it's easy for native speakers in particular to confuse them. *Flare* is correct here. This is the relevant definition of *flare* from [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flare):

> to break out or intensify usually suddenly or violently — often used with up

There is no definition of [flair](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flair) that would make sense here, especially since it's a noun.

Even professional news organizations don't always have great proofreading.

Comment: "professional news organizations..."  not many of those around anymore.